# error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Trait` in crate pallet_contracts

Tags: pallet-contracts, contracts, trait

I am performing the (add the contracts pallet to a runtime) substrate tutorial and I am getting this error

error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Trait` in crate `pallet_contracts`
--> runtime/src/lib.rs:279:24
|
279 | impl pallet_contracts::Trait for Runtime {
|                        ^^^^^ not found in `pallet_contracts`

can anyone tell me what should I do to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

There is a Parity repository called [`substrate-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node), it's a Substrate node configured to include `pallet-contracts`.

You can take a look at how the trait is implemented here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L272-L320.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement contracts' `Config`, not just `Trait`.
Use `impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime`.
Here is [my example](https://github.com/CREESTL/Crain/blob/b09671f9de7d0d61dae914be658f53b8d72b0632/runtime/src/lib.rs#L270) of implementation

Comment: I had already tried using Config but then I am getting more errors like error[E0437]: type `RentPayment` is not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`

error[E0437]: type `SignedClaimHandicap` is not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`
  
`

error[E0437]: type `TombstoneDeposit` is not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`

and many more .

Comment: Could you share a link to your github repo or pastebin with the code?

Comment: This is the link to my runtime/lib.rs file                  
 https://github.com/vitthalagarwal/Pallet-Contracts/blob/main/runtime/lib.rs

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the naming of the trait,

the `Trait` name was used for config traits in the older version of substrate. This name has been replaced with `Config`.

Therefore, instead of using:

```rust
impl pallet_contracts::Trait for Runtime {
//define types here
}
```

you should use:

```rust
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
//define types here
}
```

The errors you're getting with regards to the `RentPayment` and `SignedClaimHandicap` types are occurring because these types are non-existent. They aren't declared in the `contracts` pallet's `Config` trait (they may have been there in older versions, but have been removed).

You should use the up-to-date tutorial [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/)